# Access List items from two Lists

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

I need to show values from two different lists.There will be 2 column from **List1** and another two columns from **List2**. Two lists are connected with look up column. Please help with JavaScript code for the same.

Comment: Can you write the column names and the name of the lookup list so that  I can write the full query for you?

Comment: List 1 -- Column name:
Name, Category 
List 2- Column name
Rating , ID (Nominee ID is lookup with List 1's ID)

Comment: I wrote the query in answer.

Comment: You have appeared 1 hr ago but you did not response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say `List1` contains following columns

```
 Name, Category
```

`List2` contains

```
Rating , ID
```

`Column1` is a lookup column in `List2`

So you have to use `$expand` and `$select` for getting items

```
/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('List2')/Items?$select=Rating,List1/Name,List1/Category&$expand=List1
```

Now make a GET request to get items from two lists

```
function getItems(url) {
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + url,
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.d.results);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });
}
```

For more explanation you can check my article [CRUD Operation to List Using SharePoint 2013 Rest API](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990131/CRUD-Operation-to-List-Using-SharePoint-Rest-API).